# Who is M.A. Golding and why do they have so many accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

There is a user with the name **M. A. Golding** which keeps on appearing, with a "new" account each time, often with low to no votes.

At the time of writing:

- [There are 52 versions of this account](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/613337/m-a-golding-accounts)
- The most recent being [2017-01-08](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/76624/m-a-golding)
- Most of them have a **Creation Date** and **Last Access Date** which is the same

  - Indicating that they're single-use accounts
- At first I thought they were the same person, but I've since realised that even though [there's one account with over 3.6K rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43538/m-a-golding) (which is quite significant), the rest have less than 200 rep
- [One account has 410 rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/69305/m-a-golding) (from a single answer!)

  - So it shows that even their single contribution can be worth a fair bit
- The combined rep is **6,316**!

**What is going on here, and what do we do if we see this account?**

I can:

1. Suggest to them each time to [Merge Accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

   - But I have a feeling they won't come back with the same e-mail address so will never see that notification
2. Ping a moderator by raising a flag

   - But I'm not sure if it's the correct thing to do, since I did that once and the flag was rejected:
     [image: Image capture of Mooz' flagging history indicating that one of the flags raised to moderators about the "M.A. Golding" account was rejected by a moderator, with the reason "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"]

Comment: One day I'll learn to look for dupes *before* posting.

Comment: There’s not much to do, I suppose. Unless they’re doing something untoward, such as upvoting their own posts or mass downvoting (and I’m sure the moderators have looked into it and not found anything), they’re not really doing any harm by having multiple accounts.

Comment: It doesn't matter now as the mods will see this meta anyway, but you didn't explain to the mod team what you meant in that custom flag reason. You should be explaining the situation, perhaps link them a few example accounts or even that SEDE query you've got here. Mods aren't mind readers, if I'd seen that flag with no context I would've declined it as well.

Comment: @Robotnik It's true, that flag was s*** and should have been worded more properly.

Comment: For the record, M. A. Golding rarely (if ever) responds to comments. I can't recall if they've ever accepted an answer on the (few) questions they've asked.

Comment: I know MA Goulding from History SE. He's a good user and posts good content (which is although correct, he often doesn't provide references  and assumes that everyone knows the thing he is talking about). He doesn't register (I have asked him on a few occasions). When he loses use of one account, he creates another and uses it until he loses that one as well. If he did register and used one account, I reckon he would be a stable rep user.

Comment: @Aegon - Indeed. His answers are usually quite well thought out although he has a tendency to ramble, veer off into side discussion and a strong tendency to post extraneous information. On top of that his posts never seem to improve. Precisely what you'd expect from a user who's not interactive with his peers.

Comment: @Adamant As far as I've seen, all the M A Golding accounts are unregistered and therefore **cannot vote**. This makes any sort of sockpuppet voting fraud impossible. He did recently [answer his own question using a different account](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149267/31394), but was very clear about the fact that it was a self-answer, so no problem there either. The main reason for merging these accounts would be plain tidiness, rather than preventing abuse.

Comment: For the record, there is (now) a [registered M.A. Golding](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/76624/m-a-golding); perhaps the tides are turning

Comment: @JasonBaker - [Alan Smithee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Smithee)